# How to code "if input != a number, then..."

Tags: java, string, numbers

Well, I'm trying to figure out this thing. How would you code something like this (in Javglish):

```
if(input != a number)
{
    do something
}
```

How would I code this?

Comment: @FailedDev: I figured he meant Java-ish, as in Java based pseudocode?

Comment: @FailedDev It is obviously `Jav + Glish`. Duh.

Comment: Should I tag for [tag:javglish]? :P

Comment: A) What type is `input`, B) what to you mean by "a number" - "a *particular* number", or "any number" (ie looks like a number)

Comment: Javglish is my new language. Combo of Java and English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_a_string_is_numeric#Java:

(Poorly optimized, better examples inside the link, like the RegEx one)

```
public boolean isNumeric(String input) {
  try {
    Integer.parseInt(input);
    return true;
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // s is not numeric
    return false;
  }
```

Edit for future viewers: The aforementioned RegEx method is much more elegant, but is a little harder to follow, if you aren't familiar with Regular Expressions:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String inputData) {
  return inputData.matches("[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
}
```

Comment: if you "get it" then click the check mark at the top left of his answer...